# Ejecutar consulta base de datos en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy revisando un proyecto en C# pero no logro comprender en que momento se hace la consulta a la base de datos, ya que `objRetorno` al final contiene el resultado y es lo que retorna la función.

Pero quisiera saber en que linea es que se esta mandando a ejecutar la consulta, pienso que es en `adpAdapter.Fill(dtsRetorno, prtTabla)`, pero no comprendo, a lo que es el método Fill. Lo único que hace es llenar el contenido del `adpAdapter` a `dtsRetorno`.

```
public object Execute(string prtTabla, string prtQuery)
        {
            object objRetorno = null;

            DataSet dtsRetorno = new DataSet();
            OdbcCommand pComando = new OdbcCommand(prtQuery, pCnn);
            OdbcDataAdapter adpAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();

            try
            {
                exError = new Exception("Sin error");                
                if (bSeEstaUsandoTransaccion)
                    pComando.Transaction = pTran;

                pComando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                pComando.CommandTimeout = iTiempoDeEspera;
                adpAdapter.SelectCommand = pComando;
                adpAdapter.Fill(dtsRetorno, prtTabla);

                objRetorno = (object)dtsRetorno;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo hace en el Fill

```
adpAdapter.Fill(dtsRetorno,prtTabla);
```

Aqui la documentacion de ese método donde llena el datasource/dataset

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Common_DataAdapter_Fill_System_Data_DataTable_System_Data_IDataReader_